# Excel - If range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to look at the skill ratings displayed in columns B:G and RETURN the relevant value listed below into column A.

[image]

The different permutations I have to cover are below:

```
All 3's RETURN 3
All 2's RETURN 2
All 1's RETURN 1
Mix of 3's and 2's RETURN 2
Mix of 2's and 1's RETURN 1
Mix of 3's and 1's RETURN 2
Mix of 3's, 2's and 1's return 2
```

I used the formula below to get as close as possible to the end goal but I soon realised that the data would be inaccurate at some points.

```
=IF(SUM(B2:G2)=18,3,IF(SUM(B2:G2)=12,2,IF(SUM(B2:G2)=6,1,IF(SUM(B2:G2)<12,1,IF(SUM(B2:G2)<18,2)))))
```

Thank you in advance for any help you may offer!

Comment: Try `=INT(AVERAGE(B2:G2))`  It will get close

Comment: @ScottCraner - Here I am trying to get clever with an array formula (trying something like `=COUNTIF(B2:G2,{1,2,3}),{1,2,3}...` which isn't working at all, or trying to shove an `INDEX()` in there somehow), and you come with that. Nice thinking!

Comment: if the formulas below work correctly, 63 possible cases of 1, 1 case of 3 and 665 cases of 2, for a wopping total of 729 possible combination?

Comment: Yes that checks out because they should add up to 3^6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this

```
=FLOOR(MEDIAN(MIN(B2:G2),MAX(B2:G2)),1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, appreciated

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This should satisfy all rules:

```
=IF(AND(AVERAGE(B2:G2)<=2,COUNTIF(B2:G2,3)>0),2,INT(AVERAGE(B2:G2)))
```

[image]